# Converting an un-aware timestamp into an aware timestamp for UTC conversion

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I created a datetime that is unaware using the code below and I need to have it in UTC since the time is in "US/Eastern". I would like to make the datetime aware of EST first then convert to UTC.

```
import datetime
import pytz
from pytz import timezone
dt = "8/8/2013 4:05:03 PM"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
unaware_est = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
localtz = timezone('US/Eastern')
utc = localtz.localize(unaware_est)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/druidry-codebase/services/xignite/test.py", line 120, in <module>
    quote_time = localtz.localize(quote_time)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 303, in localize
    if dt.tzinfo is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Comment: Your string is not converting to a datetime object. Check my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `localize` method takes a `datetime`, not a string.  So the call to `strftime` should be removed.

```
import datetime
import pytz
from pytz import timezone
dt = "8/8/2013 4:05:03 PM"
unaware_est = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
localtz = timezone('US/Eastern')
aware_est = localtz.localize(unaware_est)
```

This still doesn't give you UTC.  If you want that, you need to follow it up with:

```
utc = aware_est.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - It seemed to work with `.normalize`, but your code appears to be more correct.  My guess is that UTC is special in this regard?  I updated to use `.astimezone` instead.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A Python string and datetime object are not interchangable. You need to convert them explicitly:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

# convert the time string to a datetime object
dt_str = "8/8/2013 4:05:03 PM"
unaware_est = datetime.strptime(dt_str,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

# make it a timezone-aware datetime object 
aware_est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(unaware_est, is_dst=None)

# convert it to utc timezone
utc_dt = aware_est.astimezone(pytz.utc) # `.normalize()` is not necessary for UTC

# convert it to a string
print(utc_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")) # -> 2013-08-08T20:05:03Z
```

Note: `is_dst=None` asserts that the input local time exists and it is unambigous. See [problems with local time](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime).